# Boolean not appearing in Firestore object

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Collection that keeps track of a user's message threads by storing objects called MessageThreads as documents. Here are that object's class/constructors:

```
public class MessageThread {
    private String partnerName;
    private String partnerID;
    private String threadID;
    private Message lastMessage;
    private boolean notificationsOn;


    public MessageThread() {

    }


    public MessageThread(String partnerName, String partnerID, String threadID, boolean notificationsOn) {
        this.partnerName = partnerName;
        this.partnerID = partnerID;
        this.threadID = threadID;
        this.notificationsOn = notificationsOn;
    }


    public MessageThread(String partnerName, String partnerID, String threadID, Message lastMessage, boolean notificationsOn) {
        this.partnerName = partnerName;
        this.partnerID = partnerID;
        this.threadID = threadID;
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
        this.notificationsOn = notificationsOn;
    }

    public String getPartnerID() {
        return partnerID;
    }

    public void setPartnerID(String partnerID) {
        this.partnerID = partnerID;
    }

    public String getThreadID() {
        return threadID;
    }

    public void setThreadID(String threadID) {
        this.threadID = threadID;
    }

    public boolean areNotificationsOn() {
        return notificationsOn;
    }

    public void setNotificationsOn(boolean notificationsOn) {
        this.notificationsOn = notificationsOn;
    }

    public String getPartnerName() {
        return partnerName;
    }

    public void setPartnerName(String user1) {
        this.partnerName = user1;
    }


    public Message getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }

    public void setLastMessage(Message lastMessage) {
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
    }

}
```

When the messaging activity is launched for a new thread, the `notificationsOn` boolean is set to true and a Thread object is created using the second (4 argument) constructor:

```
 private void getSetThreadDetails(final String convoID) {

        final DocumentReference threadReference = mFirestore.collection("users").document(mSignedInUserID).collection("threads").document(convoID);


        threadReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();

                    if (!snapshot.exists()) {
                        notificationsOn = true;
                        Log.d(TAG,"notifications when thread details set: " +String.valueOf(notificationsOn));
                        MessageThread newMessageThread = new MessageThread(mPartnerName, mPartnerID, convoID, notificationsOn);
                        threadReference.set(newMessageThread);

                    }



                }
            }
        });


    }
```

However, in Firebase, the stored MessageThread is not showing an entry for notificationsOn even as it is set to true right before being sent to Firebase. Where does it go?

Comment: Is that your entire MessageThread object?  If so, I would expect nothing to be stored, since all your member variables are private.  If you have getters and setters, please edit the question to show them.

Comment: Removed them for brevity. Edited them back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a setter for notificationsOn, but you don't have a getter.  Firestore (by way of JavaBean convention) needs to find the method by its correct name:

```
public boolean getNotificationsOn() {
    return this.notificationsOn;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, just mark the field as public and remove the getter and setter: `public class MessageThread {
...    public boolean notificationsOn;

`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but then there would be one public field commingled with 4 other private fields that have proper getters and setters in this example.  :-(

Comment: @Doug: yeah, I'd probably make all of them public fields at that point and drop all getters/setters. ;-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I won't argue with you about why using getters and setters and never exposing member variables is a better engineering practice. :-)

Comment: Very often I see these POJOs created as pure DTOs, where the advantage of getters and setters is minimal. That doesn't apply everywhere of course, and YYMV, although in general I don't think that just adding a getter/setter makes classes better encapsulate their internals.
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html ;-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I said I wasn't going to argue with you, and I'm sticking to it, even though you want to argue with me.  :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Well, but I will say that Kotlin did away with pure fields exposed in classes because it's such an antipattern.  There are now implicit getters and setters that you can override if you want.